# How to run concurrent (parallel) downloads with lftp?

Tags: ftp, sftp, lftp

`lftp` supposedly supports downloading mutliple files concurrently using `get -P`:

From the NEWS file:

```
Version 4.8.0 - 2017-07-10
...
* get/mget/put/mput: add -P option for parallel transfers and long options.
```

From the man page:

```
get [-E] [-a] [-c] [-e] [-P N] [-O base] rfile [-o lfile] ...

Retrieve the remote file rfile [...]
      ...
      -P N        download N files in parallel
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. Here is an excerpt of an SFTP-connected interactive session using `lftp` version **4.9.2**:

```
# testing -P 3 with three files - sees "3" as a file name
lftp username@ftp.hostname:/basedir/subdir> get -P 3 f20230719.zip f20230720.zip f20230721.zip
get: Access failed: Cannot find message [/basedir/subdir/3]
45785 bytes transferred in 7 seconds (6.9 KiB/s)
Transfer of 1 of 4 files failed

# testing -P without argument - silently ignored
lftp username@ftp.hostname:/basedir/subdir> get -P big20230708.zip big20230715.zip
`big20230715.zip' at 4390912 (4%) 927.4K/s eta:94s [Receiving data]
Interrupt
```

The online `help` for `get` doesn't know about `-P`, either (even though the man page from the same version does):

```
lftp username@ftp.hostname:/basedir/subdir> help get
Usage: get [OPTS] <rfile> [-o <lfile>]
Retrieve remote file <rfile> and store it to local file <lfile>.
 -o <lfile> specifies local file name (default - basename of rfile)
 -c  continue, resume transfer
 -E  delete remote files after successful transfer
 -a  use ascii mode (binary is the default)
 -O <base> specifies base directory or URL where files should be placed
```

Has anybody managed to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a documentation/UI problem. `get -P` does not accept any `n` value, but it isn't ignored either. Re-running the second attempt shows that *both files are in fact downloaded concurrently*.

Apart from the wrong information in the man page and the online help, the UI is quite misleading: only one download is visible at a time. The displayed download speed and ETA are for that file only, and the display switches to another concurrent download after a while.

If both files are of similar sizes, they will have similar speeds and ETA. In my second test above, the file names also only differed in one digit, making it quite hard to see what's going on.

In contrast to `get -P`, `mget -P` insists on a number after `-P` as connection limit. It's unclear how many concurrent connections `get` will use; possibly the value configured in `net:connection-limit` (which defaults to unlimited).

I'm going to file an issue about the documentation. At least it does work, after a fashion.

Comment: I'd expect concurrent connections to still sum up to the available bandwidth of your connection; so in practice, no speedup gain (and also delaying the arrival of any single file) - if that was what you expected.

Comment: Concurrent downloads are still useful if the server's bandwith per connection is artificially limited. Circumventing this by using multiple connections could be seen as abuse, but in my case it's sanctioned by the server's operator.

Comment: Well, that explains it - makes sense in that situation; a "lazy" (easy?) way to have control over bandwidth usage I suppose.